# Is it possible to add text above blurriness with CSS

Tags: html, css, blur, css-filters

I am currently working on a website which has a section what will launched soon. So what I already made is blurring the DIV I wanted to blur. My idea is to add text on it saying "Coming Soon". I'm not a CSS expert, but is that possible without blurring the text in the div?

This is what I have made so far:

```css
.blur{
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    height: 222px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">Coming Soon</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to complicate with extra markup, use pseudo element

```css
.blur {
  height: 222px;
  position:relative;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align:center;
}

.blur:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  filter: blur(5px);
  z-index:0;
}
.blur span {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur"><span>Coming Soon</span></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I put your code in my browser. It is only showing the text, and not the div. Once I remove the z-index the div comes back

Comment: @JoeyBordono i updated my code, it can be due to z-index

Comment: Can this be used to change the opacity of a background image that is placed via css `background-image: url();` and not changing the opacity to the content that is also in the div?

Comment: @UnitedProDesign yes absolutely :) you place the image in the :before and you apply opacity on it ;)

Comment: I have been trying to figure out a way to make this work.  Awesome!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a parent div, and add the blurred div and the text div in it and use position: absolute to position them on top of each other.

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="blurred"><img src="images/skldmsaklmdask.jpg"></div>
<h2 id="text">TEXT ON TOP OF DIV</h2>
</div>

<style>
#parent { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
#blurred { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    height: 222px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#text { position: absolute; top: 50%; width: 50%; left: 25%; font-size: 2vw; color: #fff; }
```

something along those lines.  Change up the styling as you see fit.

Comment: You can also get away with not having the parent div position absolute but setting its height.  If you use absolute position on the parent div, set the body or the next div up to `position: relative;`

Comment: the other option to get away from not using absolute position is to stil use parent div, have everything `float: left;` or `display: block;` and use negative margins on the text to position on top of blurred.

Answer (score 0):

For better out you need to change your html

**Try this one**

```css
.parent {
 width: 50%;
 height: 222px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.parent .blur {
 display: block;
 -moz-filter: blur(5px);
 -o-filter: blur(5px);
 -ms-filter: blur(5px);
 filter: blur(5px);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
.parent h1 {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #fff;
 z-index: 5;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Coming Soon</h1><!-- your content -->
    <span class="blur"></span><!-- blur box -->
</div><!-- parent -->
```

If you want to cut the edges add change `.parent blur` style to this

```
.parent .blur {
    display: block;
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```